# Linearize conditional constraint

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, constraint, linearization, constraint-programming

Consider a variable c from the domain {-1,0,1}. I have the following constraint:
IF $c = 1 \Rightarrow x = 1 $ ELSE $x = 0$
How do I linearize this constraint?

Comment: As a quick fix, I think you can do x >= c, x <= c+1,  x - c <= 0, assuming x is a binary variable, of course.

Comment: @J.Dionisio What you proposed forces $x=c$.

Comment: @RobPratt Ah, of course. Sorry!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might help to consider the contrapositives:
\begin{align}
x=0 &\implies c\le 0 \\
x=1 &\implies c\ge 1
\end{align}
Both of these are indicator constraints, which you can linearize via big-M:
\begin{align}
c &\le 1x \\
-c+1 &\le 2(1-x)
\end{align}
Simplifying yields
$$2x-1 \le c \le x,$$
which you could have also derived via
$$-1(1-x)+1x \le c \le 0(1-x)+1x.$$

Comment: Thanks, I need to change my other constraints a bit to implement this, but it is possible.

Comment: @RobPratt, is it possible to relax the domain of $c$ (despite of being $c$ real or integer) to make the problem readable? (e.g. $c \in \{-1..1\}$)

Comment: @A.Omidi The constraints I proposed enforce $c\in[-1,0]\cup\{1\}$.

Comment: @RobPratt, sorry for the late answer, and thanks for the clarification. Would you please, does it make any mistake to use $c \in \{-1..1\}$? As if $c$ is being integer the domain falls in {-1,0,1} and again if $c$ is being real, the questioner limited it to be {-1,0,1}.

Comment: @A.Omidi I don’t understand your question. The question specifies that $c\in\{-1,0,1\}$. If you relax integrality of $c$, my constraints would allow fractional values with $-1<c<0$. I think the notation $\{-1..1\}$ is ambiguous and would instead recommend using $\{-1,0,1\}$ for the finite set and $[-1,1]$ for the closed interval.

Comment: @RobPratt, thanks. My question was about relaxing the integrality. Now, it is clear.