# how to minimize the distance to the final points with incomplete information?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, integer-programming

Suppose we have a transportation problem similar to pickup and delivery problems. So, we have a set of drivers and a set of passengers. each passenger has predefined origins and destinations.  I'd like to know if we could compute the distance between a passenger's destinations and the drop-off nodes without having access to the solver's output.

Every riders could be picked-up and drooped-off by multiple drivers. And there's no particular order on nodes of the graph which is denoted by $N$.

We have a binary variables of $ x_{i,j}^{d,r}$ if driver $d$ drives $r$ on edge $(i,j)$
and we already know for each $r$ their start's $s_r$ and their destination's $d_r$ points ($s_r \in N$ and $d_r in N$). I'm wondering without knowing the path and values of variables from the solver how to minimize the objective as a distance between the last drop-off point and the destinations of each rider. Is this possible to compute this value implicitly and have it as an objective function or do we simply need more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define binary $e_{i}^r,s_{i}^r$ as drop-off & pickup nodes for rider $r$. 
Then assuming a rider $r$ is picked/dropped by same driver
$\sum_d(\sum_j x_{j,i}^{d,r} -\sum_jx_{i,j}^{d,r}) = e_{i}^r - s_{i}^r$

$ s_{i}^r+ e_{i}^r \le 1  \quad \forall i \ \forall r$: A node $i$ can either be origin/destination.

If you don't want to use $ s_i$ then (as used in another [response](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/10149/linearize-conditional-constraint) by Dr. Rob)
$ 2e_{i}^r - 1 \le \sum_d(\sum_j x_{j,i}^{d,r} -\sum_jx_{i,j}^{d,r}) \le e_{i}^r$

Then distance is:
if $ d_r$ may either be a node or 2-D location coordinates, then every node $i$ will also have location coordinates. So predefine distance matrix to compute
$ \sum_r \sum_i dist_{d_r,i}e_{i}^r $

Comment: @linkho yes they are binary variables. If drivers are changing, so summing over driver $d$ makes sense. This is what I have done to make it work because if you imagine a node $i$ with its edges over $j$, along that arc it should be 1 driver. Summing over drivers $d$, basically summing means 'any' driver, should make all incoming edges $\le 1$ & similarly outgoing edges $\le 1$. Then destination is always the node with only incoming edge, no outgoing. Similarly for start its only outgoing. So the relation will be either $ 1-0$ or $ 0-1$ or $ 1-1$: route, $ 0-0$: no travel.

Comment: @linkho right, my bad, no summing over $d$ in 2nd constraint.

Comment: @linkho, I assumed drop-off node $i$ is part of the arc that solver needs to figure out. Pickup node will be presented by $ s_i$. Final destination for rider $r$ is given by predefined parameter $d_r$. Is $ d_r$ one of the nodes $ i$? Or its a location coordinate? Either way need to preset a distance matrix between all $d_r$ and nodes. Then distance becomes $\sum_i dist[d_r, i]*e_i$ where $ dist[d_r,i]$ is predefined distance between $ d_r$ & every node $i$. I have updated the answer

Comment: no, sorry about the confusion. And thanks for the answer. Both $s_r$ and $d_r$ are nodes. The way I have the nodes in my network, just doesn't have any order. they jsut have some randome node ID, that's to  say $s_r  \le d_r$

Comment: @linkho so you can have a simple distance matrix I x I and for a rider, $r$, say final node is $k$ which you have called as $ d_r$, then distance will be $ \sum_i dist[k,i]* e_{i}^r$ over all riders.

Comment: My question was on part $\sum_i i e_i^r -d_r$, assuming that at node ID 6 there was a drop-off and the node ID of rider's destination is 225. then this distance formula basically return 6-225 = -219 which doesn't make sense. Am I undersating the distance correctly?

Comment: @linkho I have updated it to use a simple predefined distance matrix, like (225-6=219) or (6-225 = 219). In either case it will use 219

Comment: given that a riders can de pickup-drop off multiple time, how to know which $e_i^r$ to use?

Comment: Yes, still for a rider $r$, if dropped off by driver $d1$, then picked up by driver $d2$, at node say $i$ still there's going to be incoming & outgoing. That's why summing over drivers. Only final drop-off node $i$ will have only 1 incoming, even when summed over all drivers and summing over all other nodes $j$ connected to that node $i$.

Comment: So the node $i$ with only 1 incoming, no outgoing (1-0) will turn $e$ to 1.